# NGINX - How to add trusted certificate in nginx?

Tags: angular, rest, nginx, lua, ssl-certificate

I am working on angular application(UI) which connects with different REST servers, we have adding URL of each server as proxy in nginx and connecting to REST server but each rest server has its own cacert. So how can I add trusted certificate in nginx in this case?

Comment: Your question is tagged `lua`, but nginx on its own does not support Lua scripting. Are you using the nginx lua module or openrety?

Comment: I am using nginx lua module